# How do you define a Knockout computed Var when you call it inside a Select script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have here a JavaScript with KnockOut JS:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvd6xLjL/)

As you can see on the JS script, there is a Select `self.langSet`

that is then used by three ko.computed functions: `i1Txt`, `i2Txt`, `i3Txt`

and then comes another dropdown `self.selectionSet` where the `theDropTxt` values must take the `i[1-3]Txt` respectively.

**My Problem**:
I know that before I can use `i1Txt()`, `i2Txt()`, `i3Txt()` - I need to have them verified that they are defined just like

```
if (self.setLang()) {
        if (self.setLang().langTxt == "English") {
            return "Two Fifty";
        }
        if (self.setLang().langTxt == "Français") {
            return "Deux cent cinquante";
        }
    }
    return null;
```

where `self.setLang()` is verified as defined before using `self.setLang().langTxt`.

I tried doing this:

```
if (i1Txt() && i2Txt() && i3Txt()) {
self.selectionSet = [{
    theDropTxt: i1Txt(),
    theDropVal: selVal1
}, {
    theDropTxt: i2Txt(),
    theDropVal: selVal2
}, {
    theDropTxt: i3Txt(),
    theDropVal: selVal3
}];
}
self.setDrops = ko.observable();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvd6xLjL/1/)

(LOL)

But it's all wrong.  How do I do it right?

Comment: What's the issue? Your computed observables appear to working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest coming at the problem from a different approach. The values come from the language: why create computed fields when you can more tightly couple the language and the values?

http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/m80L37y8/

First, I added a `values` property to each language, that has the text you wanted in an array:

```
self.langSet = [{
    langTxt: "English",
    langVal: langVal1,
    values: [{
        theDropTxt: "Three Twenty",
        theDropVal: selVal1
    }, {
        theDropTxt: "Four Eighty",
        theDropVal: selVal2
    }, {
        theDropTxt: "Two Fifty",
        theDropVal: selVal3
    }]
}, {
    langTxt: "Français",
    langVal: langVal2,
    values: [{
        theDropTxt: "Trois-cent Vingt",
        theDropVal: selVal1
    }, {
        theDropTxt: "Quatre cent quatre-vingt",
        theDropVal: selVal2
    }, {
        theDropTxt: "Deux cent cinquante",
        theDropVal: selVal3
    }]
}];
```

I changed the `selectionSet` to an observableArray

```
self.selectionSet = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Lastly I added a `.subscribe` to the setLang observable so we can spot when it changes:

```
// subscribe to changes in language and change selections
self.setLang.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    // change the array 
    self.selectionSet(newValue.values);
});
```

When the setLang is changed, this triggers the subscription. This then changes the second dropdown source to use the new language. I think this is a neater solution that using computed values.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, this is a more cleaner, shorter code, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your `self.selectionSet` may be *computed* too:

```
self.selectionSet = ko.computed(function(){
    return [{
        theDropTxt: self.i1Txt(),
        theDropVal: selVal1
    }, {
        theDropTxt: self.i2Txt(),
        theDropVal: selVal2
    }, {
        theDropTxt: self.i3Txt(),
        theDropVal: selVal3
    }];
});
```

Is that what you want to get? http://jsfiddle.net/pvd6xLjL/2/

Comment: This works and a much shorter approach with few changes. How did making it a computed work without JS going all freaky and saying that "self.i1Txt() is not defined"?